# How can I split and join tags on PhpStorm for JSX? e.g: "<Link/>" to "<Link> </Link>"

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

How can I do this on PhpStorm:

Transform:

```
<Link/>
```

to

```
<Link> </Link>
```

And Vice Versa.

For Emmet we can just press Cmd + J, as the link below demonstrates:

https://docs.emmet.io/actions/split-join-tag/

This is useful because the PhpStorm is always closing the tag for Link when Tab is pressed.

If I do this:

```
Link + <TAB>
```

I get this:

```
<Link/>
```

And I was expecting to have this:

```
<Link> </Link>
```

It is strange because I was expecting the closing tag only when I put the "/" at the end, example:

```
Link/ + <TAB>
```

Comment: actually IDEA behaves just in the way expected by you: `Tag` +`tab` results in `<Tag></Tag>`, `Tag/` - in `</Tag>`. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26468#focus=streamItem-27-2337530-0-0

Comment: This is true for any other components that is not the "Link" as explained in the original question.

Comment: please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-36536 for updates

Answer (score 2):

there are **Expand empty tag** and **Collapse empty tag** intentions available on `Alt+Enter`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is great, but there is a way to have this as short cut as Emmet does? https://docs.emmet.io/actions/split-join-tag/

Comment: No, sorry:( Please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-91566#comment=27-380907